# Backward selection in LME, singularity in backsolve occured

Tags: r, mixed-models

I have data, where "speed of flight" is a response variable and `group` (experimental/control), `test` (first/second), `FL` (fuel loads, % from lean body mass: from 0 to ~25%), `wing` (wing length in mm). Since we have tested same birds twice (first and second test, experimental group was infected), I want to perform the mixed model (add a random term `~1|ring`). I also added the `weight` parameter for the `test` variable because of heteroscedasticity.

```
mod<-lme(speed~test* group * FL * wing,weight=~1|test,random=~1|ring,data=data,method="ML")
```

This is how the full model looks like (I use `nlme` package). After that I start the backward selection. I do it manually (according to the lowest AIC) and then check the result with a function `stepAIC` (MASS package). In this case first two steps of selection are well, but when I start with the model:

```
mod3<-lme(speed~test+group + FL + wing+ test:group + group:FL + FL:wing + test:group:wing, weight=~1|test,random=~1|ring,data=data,method="ML")
```

I got an error:

```
 Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM) : 
    Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1
```

As far as I understand, it means that not all interactions of factors exist. But then I should have got the same error already with the full model. And with other response variables it works well. If any of you have an idea, I would be glad!

original data

```
ring    group   wing    speed_aver  FL  test
1   XZ13125 E   75  0.62    16.2950000  first
2   XZ13125 E   75  0.22    12.5470149  second
3   XZ13126 E   68  0.39    7.7214876   first
4   XZ13127 C   75  0.52    9.1573643   first
5   XZ13127 C   75  0.17    -1.9017391  second
6   XZ13129 C   73  0.46    10.3821705  first
7   XZ13129 C   73  0.33    -0.5278261  second
8   XZ13140 C   73  0.48    13.0774436  first
9   XZ13140 C   73  0.27    18.0092199  second
10  XZ13144 C   73  0.36    7.5144000   first
11  XZ13144 C   73  0.36    9.6820312   second
12  XZ13146 E   73  0.32    14.3651852  first
13  XZ13146 E   73  0.28    20.8171233  second
14  XZ13159 C   74  0.55    20.2760274  first
15  XZ13159 C   74  0.37    19.1687500  second
16  XZ13209 E   72  0.35    8.1464000   first
17  XZ13209 E   72  0.43    10.9945736  second
18  XZ13213 E   74  0.57    5.3682927   first
19  XZ13213 E   74  0.26    1.3584746   second
20  XZ13220 C   73  0.30    6.0105691   first
21  XZ13220 C   73  0.36    -8.0439252  second
22  XZ13230 E   74  0.44    5.3682927   first
23  XZ13230 E   74  0.31    3.0025000   second
24  XZ13231 C   75  0.28    6.2504000   first
25  XZ13231 C   75  0.37    7.7267717   second
26  XZ13232 C   74  0.34    16.8592857  first
27  XZ13232 C   74  0.33    13.7800000  second
28  XZ13271 C   73  0.32    16.2268116  first
29  XZ13271 C   73  0.28    14.3651852  second
30  XZ13278 E   72  0.45    15.5757353  first
31  XZ13278 E   72  0.37    14.9503704  second
32  XZ13280 C   74  0.33    15.0386861  first
33  XZ13280 C   74  0.36    7.6214286   second
34  XZ13340 E   73  0.62    16.8294964  first
35  XZ13340 E   73  0.26    13.7261194  second
36  XZ13367 E   75  0.42    23.4071895  first
37  XZ13370 E   71  0.25    13.6159091  first
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is pretty tricky as it turns out.  I *think* the problem is that due to the way you're constructing your second formula, R is not automatically removing collinear variables from the model matrix.

**tl;dr** this is a bit stream-of-consciousness, but I think the basic take-home points are

- `lme` doesn't necessarily check/handle aliasing in a model specification for you (unlike `lm`, or to a lesser extent `lmer`)
- you can get in trouble with R's formulas if you violate *marginality*, which you've done here by including the `test:group:wing` interaction without including the `group:wing` and `test:wing` interactions. R lets you do this, but the model doesn't necessarily make sense ...  I'm a little bit surprised you  ended up with this model specification -- usually `stepAIC`, and `drop1`, and R's other built-in model simplification tools, try to respect marginality and thus wouldn't let you end up here ...
- if you *really* want to fit these kinds of models, use `lmer` (although dealing with heteroscedasticity is harder), or construct your own numeric dummy variables with `model.matrix()` ...
- checking out these kinds of aliasing problems can best be done with `model.matrix()`, outside the scope of the model-fitting (`lm`/`lme`/`lmer`) function itself ...

For simplicity I'm going to leave out the variance model (`weights=varIdent(form=~1|test)`) as it doesn't seem to be relevant to this specific problem (I didn't know that *a priori*, but tests with and without it didn't differ).

```
library("nlme")
form1 <- speed_aver~test* group * FL * wing
form2 <- speed_aver~test+group + FL + wing+
                      test:group + group:FL + FL:wing +
                      test:group:wing
mod <- lme(form1,random=~1|ring,data=dd,method="ML") ## OK
update(mod,form2)
## fails with "Singularity in backsolve" error
```

What if we try it with `lme4`?

```
## ugh, I wish I knew a better way to append to a formula
form1L <- formula(paste(deparse(form1),"(1|ring)",sep="+"))
form2L <- formula(paste(deparse(form2,width=100),"(1|ring)",sep="+"))
library("lme4")
mod2 <- lmer(form1L, data=dd)
mod3 <- lmer(form2L, data=dd)
## fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient
```

Aha! `lmer` automatically detects that the model matrix is rank-deficient.  `lm` does this automatically *and* substitutes `NA` values for the aliased terms.  At present `lmer` just drops them, although with reasonably recent versions of `lme4` the (documented but unadvertised) option `add.dropped=TRUE` to `fixef()` will put the `NA` values back in the appropriate places.

So let's investigate the model matrices:

```
X0 <- model.matrix(form1,data=dd)
c(rankMatrix(X0)==ncol(X0))  ## TRUE; both are 16

X <- model.matrix(form2,data=dd)
c(rankMatrix(X))==ncol(X)  ## FALSE; 11<12
```

Try to identify aliased columns: 12th element of `svd(X)$d` is tiny (1e-15)

```
ss <- svd(X)
(zz <- zapsmall(ss$v[,12]))  ## elements of collinear grouping
##  [1]  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.0000000 -0.4472136  0.0000000
##  [7]  0.0000000  0.0000000  0.4472136  0.4472136  0.4472136  0.4472136
```

So the sum of columns 9-12 is exactly the same as column 5 (same values, oppositite signs).  What's going on here?

```
colnames(X)[zz!=0]
## [1] "wing" "testfirst:groupC:wing"  "testsecond:groupC:wing"
## [4] "testfirst:groupE:wing"  "testsecond:groupE:wing"
```

It looks like we somehow got *all* of the levels of the test-by-group interaction interacting with wing, along with the `wing` variable itself ...

```
mm <- X[,zz!=0]
colnames(mm) <- gsub("(test|group|:wing)","",colnames(mm))
head(mm)
##   wing first:C second:C first:E second:E
## 1   75       0        0      75        0
## 2   75       0        0       0       75
## 3   68       0        0      68        0
## 4   75      75        0       0        0
## 5   75       0       75       0        0
## 6   73      73        0       0        0
```

I'm still not 100% sure why this happens, but you can see that R expands the three-way interaction include *all* four levels of the two-way interaction (which in turn interact with the continuous `wing` variable), but it's also got `wing`

```
colnames(X)
##  [1] "(Intercept)"  "testsecond"    "groupE"                
##  [4] "FL"           "wing"          "testsecond:groupE"     
##  [7] "groupE:FL"    "FL:wing"       "testfirst:groupC:wing" 
## [10] "testsecond:groupC:wing" "testfirst:groupE:wing"
##      "testsecond:groupE:wing"
colnames(X0)
##  [1] "(Intercept)"               "testsecond"               
##  [3] "groupE"                    "FL"                       
##  [5] "wing"                      "testsecond:groupE"        
##  [7] "testsecond:FL"             "groupE:FL"                
##  [9] "testsecond:wing"           "groupE:wing"              
## [11] "FL:wing"                   "testsecond:groupE:FL"     
## [13] "testsecond:groupE:wing"    "testsecond:FL:wing"       
## [15] "groupE:FL:wing"            "testsecond:groupE:FL:wing"
```

If we define a model that respects marginality, then we're OK again ...

```
form3 <- speed_aver~test*group*wing+FL*(group+wing)
X1 <- model.matrix(form3,dd)
c(rankMatrix(X1)== ncol(X1))  ## TRUE
```

And we can replicate the problem more simply this way:

```
form4 <- speed_aver~wing+test:group:wing
X2 <- model.matrix(form4,dd)
c(rankMatrix(X2)== ncol(X2))  ## FALSE
```

this model has the three-way interaction (explicitly), but is missing the two-way interaction.  If we used `~wing*test*group`, or even `~wing+wing*test*group`, we would be OK ...

```
form5 <- speed_aver~wing+test*group*wing
X3 <- model.matrix(form5,dd)
c(rankMatrix(X3)== ncol(X3))  ## TRUE
```

Comment: thank you very much! I've got your idea, indeed I violated marginality, when I started manual backward selection. The model I've got with stepAIC was rather complicated and a bit confusing (so not ver usefull), so I tried to prove it and repeated the selction process manually. Now I'll try to go through your expalnation details (not too easy for me=))and fix   the problem. And once again thank you for your help.